# Material Icon in Bootstrap Nav bar is not aligning properly

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, google-material-icons

Making use of bootstrap 4 and Material Icon in a Nav bar and icons are not aligned properly

You may see that in this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/saamisolutions/7phge3ro/5/

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-icons/3.0.1/iconfont/material-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                            <i class="material-icons">home</i>Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                            <i class="material-icons">build</i>Configuration</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                            <i class="material-icons">person</i>User Admin</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                            <i class="material-icons">more_horiz</i>More</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: I recommend you to use font awesome icons rather than materialize  when you are using Bootstrap. If you club material and bootstrap the css will be having some issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this code to your code.

```
a.nav-link {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

here is the working codepen for your code. https://codepen.io/irinnahar/pen/KjGpoL

Comment: What you do here is just fixing this _specif_ markup and classes. The real issue is remain in other places of code when using material icons.

Answer (score 1):

You can use css `vertical-align` to fix this issue. I recommend to apply to all Material Icons.

```
.material-icons {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Alternatively you may use `margin-right: 5px` for a bit more breathing space.

See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mhrabiee/t0ynL69w/1/